# Last TD and Second last TD in TR (CSS / LESS)

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

**After Google-ing and stackoverflow-ing,** I still haven't been able to solve this one:

I have a table with about a dozen rows. One of the rows looks like this:

```
<tr class="rvw-product-total">
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td>$180.67</td>
</tr>
```

The last two TDs in this row (Total and $180.67) should have a green `background-color` and `bold` text.

So I can get this accomplished in CSS/LESS like so:

```
tr[class="rvw-product-total"]:last-child td, tr[class="rvw-product-total"]:nth-child(n+2) td {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #DFF0D8;
}
```

That makes the `background-color` of the entire row green.

Then I've tried explicitly setting the `background-color` of the first TD to white, like so:

```
tr[class="rvw-product-total"]:first-child td {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

But the entire row still remains the green `background-color`, and I'm just curious what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's a quick demonstration on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acegyver/EYVvc/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first selector should be:

`table.prod-rvw-tbl tr[class="rvw-product-total"] td:last-child,`

And the second selector should be:

`table.prod-rvw-tbl tr[class="rvw-product-total"] td:nth-child(n + 2)`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYVvc/4/)

Comment: **Thank you!** Fantastic, it works. I appreciate your help and getting me back on the right track. My only excuse is that I did some careless copy & paste stuff and without you, I probably wouldn't have been able to solve this issue as quickly as I just did. Manny thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are should move `:first-child` on your last selector to `td`.

```
table.prod-rvw-tbl tr[class="rvw-product-total"] td:first-child {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Btw, your selectors are too [complex](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/). It's better for performance to reduce it.
If you are just having .rvw-product-total class on `<tr>`s of this table, than it's sufficient to put the following selector:

```
.rvw-product-total td:first-child {}
```

I turned the selectors and overwrite the `:first-child` than using `:last-child` because it's [better supported](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#link6). 
I also included the shorthand property `background` instead of `background-color`.

That should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/acegyver/EYVvc/2/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate your contribution.